# Why do I get the warning "epstool binary is not available", with saveas(gcf,'filename.pdf')

Tags: matlab, octave

I am plotting contours with octave and with the command `saveas(gcf,'rainzam.pdf')` I get the output ok, but I was just wondering why I get the following warnings:

```
warning: print.m: epstool binary is not available.
Some output formats are not available.
warning: print.m: fig2dev binary is not available.
Some output formats are not available.
```

This is not serious but if there is a way of making them disappear, I would appreciate assistance.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

As explained [here](http://wiki.octave.org/Octave_for_Microsoft_Windows), you need to install [epstool](http://pages.cs.wisc.edu/~ghost/gsview/epstool.htm) and `fig2dev` which is part of [xfig](http://www.xfig.org/userman/installation.html).

Depending on your system, there might be packages available.

For instance on `openSUSE`, just issue `cnf epstool` which yields

```
Try installing with:
    sudo zypper install epstool
```

If `cnf epstool` still yields `epstool: command not found`, then you need to subscribe to the `Publishing` repo. The easiest is to use [one-click install](http://software.opensuse.org/package/epstool?search_term=epstool).

And similarly, `sudo zypper install transfig` to get `fig2dev`.

---

Alternately, you could disable the warnings:

```
warning("off", "print.m: epstool binary is not available")
warning("off", "print.m: fig2dev binary is not available")
```

But the functionality of `epstool` and `fig2dev` would not be available then.

Comment: This works perfectly for me, I no longer have the warnings. I did "sudo apt-get install" for both epstool and for transfig. Thanks @huntj for giving me some of your precious time.